# Angular2 load image

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with including images, script or css in app with angular2.
I have image in folder `/app-name/img/image.jpg` and `<img>` tag is in 
`/app-name/src/app/my-component/my-component.component.html`:

```
<img src="../../../img/image.jpg">
```

When i load page, i get error:
 GET http://localhost:4200/img/image.jpg 404 (Not Found)

How to create url address in angular2? The same problem is when i added script url in index.html.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using angular-cli to build your project.

You need to include your `img` directory in the list of assets that needs to be copied to the output (deployable) directory.

In the `.angular-cli.json` file, add the `img` directory to the below array:

```
apps[0].assets
```

And then you can use like below

```
<img src="img/image.jpg">
```

It would be something like

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "img"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not include your `img` folder into your `src` folder,
so try to put it there and adjust your `src` attribute value to `/img/image.jpg`

in general: make sure everything you want to use inside you application is in your `src` folder. that content in there (and only that content) will then eventually be used to be processed(transpiled, bundled, minified and so on) and then end up in a webserver.

all other files outside of the `src` folder are for other purposes, like configuration files, node_modules, dist folders and so on

Comment: Its not works. Can i add "base url" for all  href or src?

Comment: your img is at "/app-name/src/img/image.jpg" and your href pointing to "/img/image.jpg" ?